# Wygwam field dissapearing

Tags: wygwam

Planning to switch from editor to wygwam, and when activating for a field for trial I get a complete blank field. The editors input-window flashes for a second, but no buttons are visible during that sec. Then all goes blank.
[image]

I have re-installed wygwam according to the installation instructions at P&T, with manual upload and no "updater" involved.
Same error regardless of Safari/Chrome/FFox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything was due to me having DevDemons Channel Images installed. 
Without their WW-plugin they seems to kill each other :/

Many Thanks Brad at P&T for sorting this out for me!

/patrick

Comment: You might want to mark your answer as the accepted answer. Also, did you mean `EE-plugin` here:  `Without their WW-plugin they...`

Comment: Would have if I could have..  :)
There's a 13hr grace period before I can mark my own answer as the "accepted answer"

Seems like IF i have the Channel Images plugin installed and activated I also need to have the DD-files copied in to the WW directory.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here using MAMP Pro - It appears that skin.js is being called, but is missing from the themes dir

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/skins/wygwam3/skin.js?t=C3HH5RL:1
```

As far as I can tell, this file is not present in the download. My guess is that this was not carried over from a previous version so if you're doing a fresh install this file will be missing.

However, if you've got a previous version, just copy the skin.js file over from

```
/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/skins/wygwam2/skin.js
```

and you should be back in business  - if you don't have a copy of V2, then you'll need to email support and notify them of this missing file.

Comment: Thanks Jamie

How much I wished that was the problem (file was actually missing) it doesn't seem to solve the issue.
I'll ping P&T on the matter and we'll se...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today, and I think I figured out that the issue was caused by my browser caching the ckeditor.js file. So if you point your browser to this file on your site:

```
/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
```

and then do a force-refresh of that page (hold shift while clicking refresh), it will force your browser to get the new js file. Then try viewing your publish page and the WYGWAM field should show up fine. Hope that is helpful!

Comment: Great! Glad to help!