# Why is WYGWAM failing after upgrade

Tags: wygwam, ee2-upgrades

I've just upgraded from EE 2.5.3 to 2.6.1 and am fighting through all the damage it's done to my site. 
At the moment I'm stuck on the seeming failure of WYGWAM (3.1.1).

I'm having the same issue which is mentioned [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12467/wygwam-field-dissapearing) but which wasn't resolved in a public or global way.

Whether editing existing content, creating new content, or even creating a new field group and channel and then creating new content with that, I see the same behavior:

The WYGWAM field flashes once quickly (blank white for new content, white with raw source content visible for existing content) and then disappears to show only the grey background of the console.

My production site still uses WYGWAM 2.3.5 but there is no evidence of a skin.js file in that package, so that "fix" mentioned in another post is not applicable.

Anybody have any ideas where I can look, or what I can do to debug this?

I haven't yet tried un-installing and reinstalling, because there doesn't seem to be a way to do that without losing all the data, which I very much want to avoid.

[**brief update**: just discovered that WYGWAM 3.1.2 is available. Installed it, problem remains.]

[Sorry, forgot to list my installed addons]
ab_pagination, assets, ce_cache, ce_str, child_categories, force_ssl, freeform, matrix, my_title_control, playa, primary_category, sitemap, str_rexp, taggable, tagstripper, trunchtml, url_encode, wygwam

Andy

Comment: Can you check your browser's console for any JS errors?

Comment: OMG, I think I'm just getting too old for this. Check the console for errors....

Comment: [sorry, got pulled away before I could finish editing that.]   OMG, I think I'm just getting too old for this. Check the console for errors.... Thanks for the tip, Brad. Can't believe I never thought to check the console. That did the trick, too. The only error was about a missing plugin file for the ckeditor, in the wygwam theme package. Soon as it was replaced, everything was just fine. Grateful for the nudge.

Comment: It seems like this is still an issue with the download.  Is there any reason when the download from Devot:ee does not contain the skin.js file?  Where can I get a download that does contain it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem: Wygwam will flash briefly on the publish page, then disappear. The console gives a 404 not found error for `/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/skins/wygwam3/skin.js?t=D09H5XK`, and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` for `ckeditor.js`, line 24. I checked the Wygwam download files, and `skin.js` does not exist in that folder.

Comment: Is that the only error in the console? Usually this is caused because there is a missing CKEditor plugin that another EE add-on is expecting to be installed (Channel Images has one, for example).

Comment: @BradBell I think this is fixed, it started working after I clicked the Wygwam link inside the fieldtypes panel. Must have run some extra update script that didn't get run along with the module.

Comment: @kgrote Yeah, that's probably it.  That's how EE lets fieldtypes trigger their update scripts and is the cause of countless hours of unnecessary debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to have been a problem unique to our site and therefore not very likely to be of help to anybody else, except, of course, in a very generic way.

That generic help would be, check your console output.

When WYGWAM "fails" in the way described here and in at least one other similar question, the cause is often missing files in the theme package, and those will be noted in the console output.

In our case it was an addition we had made ourselves, to be able to add a number of styled pull-quote boxes to content entered in a WYGWAM field. Three of us had completely forgotten about that obscure little folder nested many layers deep in the wygwam theme folder, and it had simply not been moved across in the upgrade.

Thanks again to Brad Bell, for a nudge in the right direction.

A